# projective hypersurface and lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

Let $H\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a  definened by an irriducible homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. I would check that there is at last a line $\mathbb{P}^1$ such that the intersection number of $H$ with $\mathbb{P}^1$ is equal to $d$.

Any help is well accepted

Comment: What is your definition of intersection number? Any line would intersect $H$ at $d$ points counting multiplicity by Bezout's theorem.

Comment: I guess the point is the existence of a line which is transverse to $H$?

Comment: I mean $d$-points counted without multiplicity.